# Redirect Inside AJAX Callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

In my application I am calling an AJAX request and after that request happens I would like to redirect to a different path. The issue I'm having is I don't exactly know how to do this. I was told been hinted to that I could "render json and respond to it inside the callback of the ajax request.", but I have been trying for quite a while and don't quite get it.

AJAX:

```
    $.ajax({
      url: sub_url,
      type: 'POST',
      data: form_data
    }).success(function(){
      //stuff
    }).fail(function(){
      //stuff
    });
```

Update action:

```
def update    
  current_submission.update_attributes(secret_params)    

  render :json => { :message => "Success!" }
end
```

My AJAX request and render json all work fine, I'm lost on how to redirect though. Simply putting `redirect_to` in the `update` method does nothing. The only solution I have found so far is this:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js { render js: "window.location.href = '#{mypath_path}'" }
end
```

which I was told was bad practice and I assumed so when I found the code.

A little push in the right direction would be great, I am still not fully aware of how/when/what order the AJAX request and the rails action fire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return info about the path that you wish to redirect to in the JSON response:

```
def update    
  current_submission.update_attributes(secret_params)    

  render :json => { :new_path => "#new_path" }
end
```

Then use `location.replace()` within the `success` function to update the browser url:

```
$.ajax({
  url: sub_url,
  type: 'POST',
  data: form_data
}).success(function(d){
  // update location on success
  location.replace(d.new_path);
}).fail(function(){
  //stuff
});
```

Comment: Consider using `.replace()`.

Comment: @dana Awesome, it works perfectly. I'm trying to understand this. It looks like `d` is the object pulled from my `render json` in my action. Then it is getting passed into the function inside of the success function. From here we are replacing the location with the data we access from the passed in object (`d.new_path`).

Is that right? If so, I had no idea that is how/when render worked in this case.

Comment: Your controller is taking a dictionary/map and serializing it to JSON.  jQuery makes this available to the `success` function in the first argument.  If you use Fiddler, you can see the result being sent across the wire.  To be honest, I have never actually used Ruby :)  But I have done similar things in Python and .NET.